# How to upgrade a secret house

Tags: house-rules

#### Context

The players got a secret manor as a gift from a shady noble woman they made friends with but the manor is old and run down since the manor has been abandon for years. They no longer have connection with noble woman due to reasons. And the manor comes with a demon butler that is sworn to serve whoever is the owner of the manor. (Think Black Butler but can't leave the property)

#### Question

How do I set it up so they could upgrade it while still keeping the location and the existence of the manor a secret?

I was thinking about having the manor tied to the demon so in order to upgrade the house they would have to increase his power, like the house looks run down but clean at the beginning but as he gets power the manor will look more pristine and he will have greater ability to make changes as ordered by summoning the upgrades. But I'm not sure.

Comment: You tagged this issue house rules, but house rules for what game?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. What RPG/edition are you asking about? You can indicate this by editing the appropriate tag (e.g. [dnd-5e] or [blades-in-the-dark]) into your post. Once you do that, the question can hopefully be reopened and answered. Hope you stick around! :)

Comment: @Theik I think it’s “house rules” as in “rules regarding houses,” not customized rulesets.

Comment: There are some questions, where you are trying to generate ideas, that fit a forum format batter than a Q&A format that this site adheres to.  We have [a curated list of forums here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566)